# Can not get the module by composer

Tags: composer

My Drupal Version is 9.5.10
PHP Version 8.1.18
I am trying to get the module:
`composer require 'drupal/rocket_chat:^3.0'`

But unsuccessful:
Problem 1

- Root composer.json requires drupal/rocket_chat, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

composer.josn

```
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8",
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
    ],
    "require": {
        "bower-asset/swagger-ui": "^5.1",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
        "drupal/advanced_cors": "^1.4",
        "drupal/aet": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.29",
        "drupal/captcha": "^2.0",
        "drupal/chat_livehelperchat": "^1.3",
        "drupal/colorbox": "^2.0",
        "drupal/configure_contextual_links": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.5",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.5",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.5",
        "drupal/country": "^1.1",
        "drupal/dashboards": "^2.1",
        "drupal/date_popup": "^2.0",
        "drupal/dbug": "^2.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^5.1",
        "drupal/diff": "^1.1",
        "drupal/draggableviews": "^2.1",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.4",
        "drupal/entity_reference_views": "^1.1@beta",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.4",
        "drupal/file_entity": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/flags": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/flood_control": "^2.3",
        "drupal/fpa": "^4.0",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^4.0",
        "drupal/imce": "^3.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui": "^1.6",
        "drupal/libraries": "^4.0",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/media_bulk_upload": "^3.0",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^4.0",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.15",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
        "drupal/phone_number": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.7",
        "drupal/rdf": "^2.1",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.2",
        "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/services": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/site_verify": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/smart_date": "^4.0",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.2",
        "drupal/swagger_ui_formatter": "^4.0",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/username_validation": "^1.2",
        "drupal/userpoints": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_autocomplete_filters": "^1.4",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^4.2",
        "drupal/views_dates": "^1.1",
        "drupal/watchdog_prune": "^2.3",
        "drupal/xmlrpc": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.4",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
    "installer-types": ["bower-asset", "npm-asset"],
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
        "type:bower-asset",
        "type:npm-asset"
            ],
        "web/libraries/swagger-ui": ["bower-asset/swagger-ui"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This JSON file doesn't follow composer's rules. You can't have the same key multiple times in the same object `{}` . Fix your `repositories[]` entry

Comment: what should i fix in repositories[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repositories section is syntactically broken. It should be:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
],
```